# What might cause invalid syntax from ArcPy with Raster Calculator and Multiple Rasters?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I am having trouble for writing script in Python (ArcGIS 10.1). The task is generally divide each raster by 100. I have many of these raster files...

So what I've done is the following:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
  arcpy.workspace="C:/Users/Vaio/.../Monthly_Original.gdb"
  rasterlist=arcpy.ListRasters(p)
  for k in range():
     OutRaster=(Raster(rasterlist[k])/100
     OutRaster.Name='p_2000_*.*'
     OutTaster.Save(OutRaster.Name)
```

I have an Error in line 6. I am very new to any sort of programming.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Perhaps the error is really in the last line - OutTaster should be OutRaster?

Comment: sorry, it was OutRaster, but the error was "invalid syntax (line 6)
"

Answer (score 6):

Insert 'import arcpy' at the top of your code (*NameError: name 'arcpy' is not defined*)

No indentation needed after the import statements

Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license using 'arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")' (*RuntimeError: ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.*)

Assuming that 'arcpy.workspace="C:/Users/Vaio/.../Monthly_Original.gdb"' is not the actual directory path run in the code, but merely abbreviated for posting here - you still need to state arcpy`.env`.workspace

'ListRasters(p)' needs to have the variable 'p' previously defined (*NameError: name 'p' is not defined*)

'range()' expects atleast one argument - or try something like for '`k in rasterlist:`' (*TypeError: range expected at least 1 arguments, got 0*)

**This is the reason for the invalid syntax error:** 'OutRaster=(Raster(rasterlist[k])/100' has **two opening parentheses but only one closing parenthesis**

Do not use '.Name' for assigning the output name (*AttributeError: 'Raster' object has no attribute 'Name'*) Note: (lower case) '.name' is Read Only

What are the '*' in 'p_2000_*.*' supposed to mean? If you want variables then you may need a counter variable defined, or extract the original file name from the item used in the for loop with rasterlist to replace the first '*' (perhaps the second '*' could be replaced with the text for the desired output raster file extension). The '*' characters used in the output name will cause more errors. (*RuntimeError: ERROR 010093: Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported.*)

The very last line needs to be changed from 'OutTaster' to 'OutRaster' (*NameError: name 'OutTaster' is not defined*)

The '.save' cannot be capitalized (*AttributeError: 'Raster' object has no attribute 'Save'*)

EDIT: Now that I finally have access to the software I was able to revise your code - you may need to modify to suit your actual data (see comments and [online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000wt000000)):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
# Set the workspace environment
arcpy.env.workspace="C:/Users/Vaio/FULLPATHNAME/Monthly_Original.gdb"
# Create a list of raster files
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()
# Loop through the actual list of rasters generated by ListRasters()
for k in rasterlist:
    print k # Optional visual check of file name
    # Divide each existing raster by 100
    OutRaster = Raster(k) / 100
    # Specify the output name variable - modify as needed
    # This example adds prefix 'p_' to original file name with extension included
    OutRaster_Name = 'p_' + k
    # Save the output raster
    OutRaster.save(OutRaster_Name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you suggest the best way to define 'p' variable?

Comment: @Irina have a read of http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001s000000 to see what ListRasters takes.

Comment: The 'p' variable would have to be defined as a wild_card or raster_type when used in ListRasters; e.g. **p = "TIFF"** in a line previous to **arcpy.ListRasters("*", p)**. The code sample in the online link @Nathan W indicated above will show you the possible parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I always put a "r" in front of any path so it is interpreted correctly. So turn

arcpy.workspace="C:/Users/Vaio/.../Monthly_Original.gdb"

into

arcpy.workspace = **r**"C:/Users/Vaio/.../Monthly_Original.gdb"

Comment: I believe the OP is correct in their paths.  There are three correct ways to express paths in Python: 1) "C:/temp" 2) "C:\\temp" or 3) r"C:\temp".